# How to search-and-replace list item names using SPServices and SharePoint 2010?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, sharepoint-2010, spservices

My goal is to modify list items (including display names, filenames, titles, URLs, etc) throughout our SharePoint site.  This is needed due to a major business reorganization which has altered the business hierarchy and project names.  We have way too many files and URLs to edit them manually.  We need to perform the equivalent of a search-and-replace operation on all list items throughout the SharePoint site.  So far, the code examples we've discovered for updating list items have all been simple set-a-flag styles of operations using the same values for all list items, but we need to read the contents of each list item and use those values as part of the newly-updated values (unless SPServices/SharePoint has some equivalent of Unix grep/sed commands).

For development and testing, I have added the following HTML/javascript code into a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP)'s HTML section which is located on my MySite's Contents page (because I really do not want to experiment against live production data), and this MySite also includes lots of text/DOC/PPT/XLS files with various names/titles/etc to search through.  For now, this script attempts to modify a single file named "test4 blah.txt" (eventually I will replace this CAMLQuery to modify multiple sets of files).  The javascript executes without errors, successfully finds the queried-for list items, and displays the supposedly-modified list items in the GUI with the supposedly-modified new values (i.e. everything looks successful from the user's point of view of the GUI), but unfortunately behind the scenes, the actual list items in SharePoint are never actually modified.  No error messages were printed into the javascript console when this script executes.  In the code's UpdateListItems section, we have tried lots of variations on internal static-names, display-names, etc with no success.

We are using Microsoft SharePoint 2010, SPServices (jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js), and jQuery (jquery-1.11.0.min.js).  I have full Site Collection Administrator privileges.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://MySiteName123/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://MySiteName123/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>

        <title>Edit the file</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <style type="text/css">
            .btn {
                font-family: verdana;
                font-weight: normal;
                cursor: pointer;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-size: 16px;
                background: #3498db;
                padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
                text-decoration: none;
                }
            .btn:hover {
                background: #3cb0fd;
                text-decoration: none;
                }
        </style>        

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Define some of our variables as "global" (to be accessible from our jQuery external libraries).
            var modifiedListItems = 0;
            var modifiedListItemsAttempted = 0;
            var ms2min = 1 / (1000 * 60);  // constant to convert milliseconds into minutes

            function EditTheFile() {
                myStartDate = new Date();
                $("#ScriptStatus").show();
                $('#ScriptStatus').append("Started running at " + myStartDate + "<br>");

                // Loop through all sites in the site collection
                GetAllSites();

                myEndDate = new Date();
                myDuration = (myEndDate - myStartDate) * ms2min;  // date differences are calculated in milliseconds    
                $('#ScriptStatus').append("Finished running at " + myEndDate + "; duration was " + (Math.round(myDuration * 100) / 100) + " minutes" + "<br>");
                $('#ScriptStatus').append("Number of modified List Items = " + modifiedListItems + " out of " + modifiedListItemsAttempted + " attempts" + "<br>");
            }    

            function GetAllSites() {
               $().SPServices({
                    operation: "GetAllSubWebCollection",
                    async:false,
                    completefunc: function (xData, status) {
                        $(xData.responseXML).find("Webs > Web").each(function() {           
                            mySiteTitle = $(this).attr("Title");
                            mySiteURL = $(this).attr("Url");
                            GetAllLists(mySiteURL);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }  // end of GetAllSites      

            function GetAllLists(mySite) {
                $().SPServices({
                    operation: "GetListCollection",
                    webURL: mySite,
                    async: false,
                    completefunc: function (xData, status) {
                        $(xData.responseXML).find("List").each(function() {
                            myListTitle = $(this).attr("Title");
                            myListURL = $(this).attr("DefaultViewUrl");
                            myListType = GetListType( $(this).attr("BaseType") );           
                            ModifyListItemURL(mySiteURL, myListURL, myListTitle); 
                        }); 
                    }  
                }); 
            }  // end of GetAllLists            

            function ModifyListItemURL(myURL, myListURL, myListName) {
                $().SPServices({
                    operation: "GetListItems",
                    webURL: myURL,  
                    listName: myListName,  
                    async: false,
                    CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>test4 blah</Value></Contains></Where></Query>",
                    CAMLViewFields: '<ViewFields Properties="True"/>',
                    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode('z:row').each(function() {
                            var listItemID = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
                            var myListItemName = $(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef");  // SharePoint display-name of "Name" is equivalent to internal-name of "FileLeafRef" 
                            var myListItemURL = $(this).attr("ows_EncodedAbsUrl");  // SharePoint display-name of "Encoded Absolute URL" is equivalent to internal-name of "EncodedAbsUrl" 
                            var myListItemTitle = $(this).attr("ows_Title");

                            // Modify the local variable's text values.
                            var new_myListItemName = myListItemName.replace("blah", "doubleplus-blah");
                            var new_myListItemURL = myListItemURL.replace("blah", "doubleplus-blah");
                            console.log("stevie17 modifyTheData for Name, oldString=" + myListItemName + ", newString=" + new_myListItemName);
                            console.log("stevie18 modifyTheData for EncodedAbsUrl, oldString=" + myListItemURL + ", newString=" + new_myListItemURL);
                            myListItemName = new_myListItemName;
                            myListItemURL = new_myListItemURL;

                            // Modify the data to have the newly-modified text values.
                            $().SPServices({
                                operation: 'UpdateListItems',
//                                webURL: myURL,    
                                listName: myListName, 
                                async: false,
                                updates: '<Batch><Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">'
                                    + '<Field Name="ID">' + listItemID + '</Field>'
//                                    + '<Field Name="FileLeafRef">' + myListItemName + '</Field>'
//                                    + '<Field Name="EncodedAbsUrl">' + myListItemURL + '</Field>'
//                                    + '<Field Name="Name">' + myListItemName + '</Field>'
//                                    + '<Field Name="Encoded Absolute URL">' + myListItemURL + '</Field>'
                                    + '<Field Name="ows_FileLeafRef">' + myListItemName + '</Field>'
                                    + '<Field Name="ows_EncodedAbsUrl">' + myListItemURL + '</Field>'
                                    + '</Method></Batch>',
                                completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                                    modifiedListItemsAttempted++;

                                    // Append information to the display table.
                                    $('#ListInfoTable > tbody:last').append("" +
                                        "<tr>" +                                                    // Start row
                                        "<td>" + mySiteURL + "</td>" +                                  // Site URL
                                        "<td>" + mySiteTitle + "</td>" +                    // Site Title   
                                        "<td>" + myListName + "</td>" +                         // List Title          
                                        "<td>" + myListURL + "</td>" +                                  // List URL
                                        "<td>" + myListType + "</td>" +                                 // List Type                                        
                                        "<td>" + myListItemURL + "</td>" +                              // List Item URL                                        
                                        "<td>" + myListItemName + "</td>" +             // List Item Name
                                        "<td>" + myListItemTitle + "</td>" +                            // List Item Title
                                        "</tr>" + 
                                        "");                            

                                    if (Status != "success") {
                                        alert("Something went wrong with the update procedure.");
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        modifiedListItems++;
                                    }
                                }
                            });             
                        });
                    }
                });
            }  // end of GetListItemURL

            // Display a human-readable form for the item type.
            function GetListType(myBaseType) {
                var myBaseTypeDescription;
                if       ( myBaseType == 0 ) { myBaseTypeDescription = "Generic List"; }
                else if  ( myBaseType == 1 ) { myBaseTypeDescription = "Document Library"; }
                else if  ( myBaseType == 2 ) { myBaseTypeDescription = "Unused"; }
                else if  ( myBaseType == 3 ) { myBaseTypeDescription = "Discussion Board"; }
                else if  ( myBaseType == 4 ) { myBaseTypeDescription = "Survey"; }
                else if  ( myBaseType == 5 ) { myBaseTypeDescription = "Issue"; }
                else                         { myBaseTypeDescription = "None"; }

                return myBaseTypeDescription;
            }  // end of GetListType            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Display GUI controls for the query operations. -->
        <div>
            <span class="btn" style="width:100px; text-align:center; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:10px; display:inline-block" onClick="javascript:EditTheFile();">Edit the file</span>
        </div>

        <!-- Display summary statistics about the query results. -->
        <div id="ScriptStatus" style="padding:5px; margin-bottom:10px; border:thin gray solid; display:none;">
        </div>

        <!-- Display a table with the query results. -->
        <table id="ListInfoTable" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr bgcolor="#E4E4E4">
                    <th>Site URL</th>
                    <th>Site Title</th>
                    <th>List Title</th>
                    <th>List URL</th>
                    <th>List Type</th>
                    <th>ListItem URL</th>
                    <th>ListItem Name</th>
                    <th>ListItem Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>        
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you're trying to accomplish, I'd suggest you invest in a third party tool like Sharegate. Making across the board changes like you seem to need will be far easier than writing code, and the tool will serve you well for other purposes as well.

If you decide to stick with the coding route, you'll need to get good at debugging JavaScript in the console. UpdateListItems will give you errors in the response (sometimes they may not make sense) and you'll need to learn how to handle them.

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestion about javascript debugging with SPServices. (Is there such a thing as "good at debugging JavaScript"?  :)

Comment: I have replaced the "if (Status != "success")" javascript code with the following error handler code:

<pre> <code> // Check for errors in the call to UpdateListItems.
var commandResponseInfo = $(xData.responseXML);
console.log("stevie19 commandResponseInfo=" + commandResponseInfo.text());
var errorCode = $(xData.responseXML).find('UpdateListItemsResult').attr('ErrorCode');
if (errorCode == "Unknown") {
    var errorMessage = $(xData.responseXML).find('UpdateListItemsResult').attr('ErrorMessage');
    console.log ("Error in UpdateListItems: " + errorMessage);
    return; 
}

Comment: When I execute the javascript which tries to update "ows_FileLeafRef" and "ows_EncodedAbsUrl", I see that the console output includes the message "commandResponseInfo=0x81020014One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields."  This makes sense...

Comment: ...so I altered the code to update "FileLeafRef" and "EncodedAbsUrl" instead.  Upon execution, the console output now includes a message "commandResponseInfo=0x00000000" (i.e. a successful command)... but the SharePoint List Item was not actually modified!  The file "test4 blah.rtf" still has the same unmodified filename and URL.  Unfortunately, the UpdateListItems command did not actually work.

Comment: You happen to have picked one of the trickier fields to update: the file name. Do you want to change the file name or the Title?

And, yes, you can get very good at debugging JavaScript - just ask any Web developer who is any good!

Comment: First of all, my thanks to you for spending effort on this.

Comment: At minimum, I would like to change any data that a typical SharePoint user would see.  Ideally, I would also like to modify the behind-the-scenes data (so users do not get confused when the displayed filenames/titles/etc do not match URLs to those items).  For now, I've been concentrating on modifying List Items, but I would also like to modify anything else within SharePoint (URLs and filenames, views, forms, menus, webpage titles and labels, permission groups, workflows).

Comment: You can't update all fields in this way, which is another reason to want a more robust tool. You're going to spend a lot of time and effort writing the code, and it won't work in all cases. Plus, your name and a new date/time stamp will appear on any list or library item you update.

Answer (score 1):

With SharePoint SOAP and REST services, success means that the query has been successfully submitted, not necessarily successfully executed. You could get a 20x status returned, but an error message in the returned data.

This page gives you an example of how to update items in a document library:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.14).aspx

Warning: there's a threshold on UpdateListItems, you can update a maximum of 160 items per call (I am not sure how SPServices handles this).

Comment: SPServices doesn't handle going beyond that threshold (which may vary across versions). You just need to build valid calls.

Comment: Thanks for the reference - this helped confirm that my <Batch> tags contain a reasonable structure. Before trying a SOAP/REST solution, I would prefer to leverage the powerful SPServices library if possible...but I will keep this option in mind.

Comment: You are already using the SOAP services, SPServices is just a wrapper around them. As for your batch, I think the issue is not the structure but rather the field names.

Comment: Ahh - I meant trying to avoid pursuing a purely SOAP/REST solution (without the SPServices to ease the pain).

My originally-posted code did have a problem with the field names, as you hinted at.  However, if you read my follow-on comments, my code now has the proper field names and receives a "commandResponseInfo=0x00000000" during execution, but the SharePoint data is still not being modified.

We are making progress, and I thank you for your help on this.

Comment: I saw your comment, but I am afraid you're not targetting the correct fields (see the sample I linked to). As for SPServices, it won't take out the pain of writing the CAML and working in small batches (see Marc's comment above).

Comment: The referenced website had an example of an Update using "<Field Name='FileRef'>" which is the Internal Name for the URL Path value. I tried that within my code: I get that value, the commandResponseInfo returns 0x00000000... and it still does not modify the List Item's data.

Comment: So far, I have tried to modify the fieldnames 
"ows_FileLeafRef", "ows_EncodedAbsUrl", "Encoded Absolute URL" (all three generate the "0x81020014One or more field types are not installed properly" error message), and I've tried "FileLeafRef", "EncodedAbsUrl", "Name", "FileRef" (all of these return a 0x00000000 successful command)... and none of them have actually modified the List Item's data.

Comment: Have you tried to just follow the sample, including in particular `owshiddenversion` and `BaseName`?

Comment: I can retrieve the value of "owshiddenversion" (i.e. var myListItemVersion = $(this).attr("owshiddenversion")) for these List Items, but it is a value of "undefined". Any attempt to add <Field Name="owshiddenversion"> into my UpdateListItems command causes a SoapServerException.